# Convert date created by jquery datepicker into a standard mysql dateformat

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date, datetime

I am using the following jquery date & time picker on a diary page. 
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#rest_examples

Its quick and easy to use and makes a date thats easy to read but the problem I am having is that im not sure how on earth to convert it to a standard mysql date format to save it to the database.

At the moment when I select a date and time it will add it to the timedate input box as something like this >> 
Wed January 9, 2013 01:43 pm

If I then hit submit, it doesn't get saved to the database.

Does anyone know how I can convert this into a format in the php that processes the posted data and save it as usual, as its driving me round the bend trying to work out a way of converting it ?.

The code im currently using for the jquery part is the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#timedate').datetimepicker({
timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
dateFormat: "D MM d, yy"
 });});</script>
```

which creates a date like :

```
 Wed January 9, 2013 01:43 pm
```

Comment: Have you tried editing the format inside the `timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
dateFormat: "D MM d, yy"`

Comment: Read the "Formatting" tab on the page you linked.  It gives you all teh information you need to determine your date format.

Comment: I have read the formatting tab but I dont want the user to have to view the date as mysql format, its supposed to be user friendly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("D F d, Y H:i a", 'Wed January 9, 2013 01:43 pm');
echo $datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

[Confirmed working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QKoqfG)

Comment: Would be best to format this properly in javascript using the option that the datepicker already has.  No need to transform the data in two different places.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this software so i wasn't even sure this was an option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following options for your datepicker formats:

```
timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
```

Comment: This works, but at the expense of user friendlessness for the user.