# Convert date format to mysql timestamp

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Very stumped about this,

I have a text input field that allows the user to insert a date and time with jquery's date picker and a timepicker addon. When the user closes the calendar to insert the date, It enters this into the text field: `10/13/2013 22:16`. How do I convert this with php to a mysql timestamp function suitable for database storage? `2013-10-13 22:16:00`

Thank You!

Comment: Check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505984/convert-date-created-by-jquery-datepicker-into-a-standard-mysql-dateformat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only logical way I've figured out how to accomplish this with PHP.

```
$Data  = $_POST['date'];
$Data  = explode("/", $Data);
$Month = $Data[0];
$Day   = $Data[1];
$YearAndTime = explode(" ", $exp[2]);
$Year = $YearAndTime[0];
$T = explode(":", $YearAndTime[1]);
$Hour = $T[0];
$Minute = $T[1];
$timestamp = "{$Year}-{$Month}-{$Day} {$Hour}:{$Minute}:00";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the builtin `DateTime` class:

```
// Create a DateTime instance from a custom format
$format = 'm/d/Y H:i';
$date   = '10/13/2013 22:16';
$time   = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);

// If the $time variable is false then it means
// that the input is not formatted correctly...
if ( ! $time) {
    echo 'Input is not formatted correctly!';
} else {
    echo 'Valid input: ', $time->format('r');
}
die;
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following in PHP:

```
$date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime( $_POST['date']));
```

Answer (score 0):

well, have you tried php [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery UI datepicker, then CIRCLE's answer is the right one.  Changing the datepicker format to yy-mm-dd will turn 9/4/2014 into 2014-09-04 which can then be successfully compared against a timestamp stored in the database.